# Getting started with Redux in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, redux-framework

I apologize if this has been asked before, but after doing some research, I could not find any resources answering this specific question of mine.

I'm trying to use the Redux framework in my WordPress theme. I used the builder to get started, which is linked to on the [plugin page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework/). I customized my framework there and chose the option of "embed only" (Embed Only: TGM is not used and Redux is embedded within the theme/plugin). I also exported as a custom theme, which uses Underscores. As a result, I now have admin directory inside of my theme, with an "options-init.php" file in it. I've been modifying this file to add my options. Is this right? In the [documentation](https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/getting-started/) it mentions to look for a sample-config.php file, and to copy that and modify it, but I can't find that anywhere. I want to make sure I'm doing this right before I get too far and find an issue.

Also, how do I make sure the framework stays up to date with the latest security patches? Is it a better idea to install it as a plugin rather than embed it in the theme itself?

Comment: I've re-tagged your post, but for future reference - the `redux` tag is for the [Redux](http://redux.js.org) JavaScript library. You want `redux-framework` for the WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Lead dev of Redux Framework here. It is very much a better idea to run Redux via a plugin if you want your users to have security updates.

Another option is to embed redux, but to use TGM to suggest for users to install the plugin. This way your theme is not dependent on Redux, but the moment they install the plugin, that version of Redux will take over.

It's up to you, but the plugin is the way to go.